# Linguagem de programação que não necessitem instalação prévia

Tags: linux, windows, instalador

Quais linguagens eu poderia simplesmente criar um programa, mandar pra alguém e ele o executar sem necessidade de instalar? Por exemplo o Java exige um software instalado anteriormente para poder rodar.

Se nenhuma linguagem assim exista, então, seria possível criar um tipo de 'auto-download'? Por exemplo, eu mando um arquivo pra alguém, ele abre o arquivo, é baixado os arquivos necessário, e então executado o programa? Seria isso possível em alguma linguagem?

Preciso que rode em Linux e Windows.

Comment: o exemplo do Java, é de que você precisa instalar ele pra executar arquivos

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 9):

Quase todas as linguagens compiladas são exatamente assim, você cria o programa, compila, gera um executável e pode mandar para a pessoa.

Se vai ter que fazer uma instalação desse executável ou não é outra coisa. Afinal certas aplicações são complexas, exigem uma interação com o sistema operacional que não pode só executar um arquivo binário enviado. Além disso mesmo podendo fazer desta forma, pode ser que precise de alguns arquivos, ainda que não precise de instalação, não é só mandar um arquivo simples.

É possível gerar um executável simples que faça a instalação para você do seu jeito. Dá para fazer isso virtualmente em qualquer linguagem, com mais ou menos facilidades. Na maior parte dos casos não compensa, ainda que eu goste dessa técnica para certas aplicações. Algumas linguagens possuem algo mais ou menos pronto para isto.

As linguagens interpretadas costumam exigir um interpretador instalado. Uma delas tem um interpretador em praticamente todos computadores (embutida no navegador), o [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Algumas linguagens compiladas exigem um ambiente de execução pré-instalado, é o caso do citado Java e do [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)). O C# usa o ambiente .NET que quase todo Windows tem instalado, portando executaria direto. Mas o C# já tem como gerar executável independente, mesmo [sem a presença do .NET](https://dotnet.github.io/) e rodando em outras plataformas que não o Windows. Isso vale para [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) também.

Há pelo menos duas linguagens que eu conheço que usa uma técnica semelhante a citada sobre o C#. [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) (com algum esforço manual) e [Harbour](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(compilador)) ([Clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(programming_language)) já fazia isto) geram executáveis através de um compilador de C, e mesmo possuindo uma máquina virtual ela é embutida nesse executável.

Sei que algumas podem gerar executável opcionalmente, [Pyhton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python) é um exemplo. Até o [PHP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) pode fazer algo assim, apesar de incomum e com resultados insatisfatórios até o momento desta resposta. JavaScript também pode fazer isto. Alguns dialetos de linguagens interpretadas também podem fazer isto. [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)) por exemplo.

Entre as linguagens compiladas que podem fazer isso as mais óbvias são [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) e [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). Também [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(software)) e outros dialetos de [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)), vários dialetos de [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC). [Objective C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), [D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)), [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)), [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), [OCaml](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml) e [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)) são outras modernas que fazem isto. Até onde sei [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) também pode. Vou evitar falar de todas muito desconhecidas ou que pouquíssimas pessoas usam (legadas ou super-nichos).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, minuciosa por sinal. O que eu quero fazer, é um projeto simples. Um tipo de 'rede social', só que muito mais basica, e no estilo CMD[Uma tela preta, com os escritos em branco], da qual eu mande um arquivo pra pessoa, ela execute-o e então ele possa conversar comigo, as partes da programação não me incomodam, o que me incomoda é a linguagem pra isso, qual seria a melhor, não quero que a pessoa tenha que pré-instalar alguma coisa pra poder simplesmente conversar, e, este projeto é só pra me motivar a aprender uma linguagem especifica, já que estou indeciso quanto a isso.

Comment: Não tem como responder isto. E nem importa também. Você tem que usar o que sabe. Mas pra ser bem sincero, quando se pergunta isto, está longe de poder começar fazer algo que vá dar certo. E não é assim que se aprende programar.

Comment: @proXy o bigown tem razão, a sua pergunta só demostra o você ainda precisa aprender muita coisa antes de sair por ai a programar. Programar toda a gente consegue, mas fazer aplicações como deve ser tem muito que se lhe diga.