# Como funciona o JVM, Java, JDK e JRE?

Tags: java, jvm, .exe, jdk, jre

O Java consegue compilar para `.exe`?

Todo sistema operacional, tais como Windows, MacOS, Linux, etc. já vem com a JVM instalada para interpretar o programa feito em Java? Ou quando compila o programa `b.exe` já vem com a JVM embutida?

Porque para usar um programa Java precisa do JRE, e para desenvolvê-lo precisa de um JDK?

Answer (score 7):

> O Java consegue compilar para `.exe`?

Java é uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) portanto ela não define esse tipo de coisa. Uma [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) específica da linguagem pode gerar um `.exe` e de fato algumas o fazem, mas não a mais comum que as pessoas usam.

E gerar um `.exe` só faz sentido mesmo no Windows, certo? É um pouco mais complicado do que isso, mas para simplificar seria assim.

Se quer saber se o compilador gera um arquivo binário que é capaz de ser executado de alguma forma, então aí sim, o `.class` é esse arquivo (também tem o `.jar`). A extensão não define se pode ser executado, define, se conformar com o conteúdo dentro um formato específico de binário que alguns sistemas operacionais entendem.

Se quer saber se ele gera um binário nativo que roda diretamente no processador, aí esse `.class` não é assim, ele é um *bytecode* que será [JITtado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101).

Existe implementação que ter um binário intermediário, semelhante ao `.class`, mas um pouco diferente e quando é instalado é gerado um binário nativo para o sistema operacional executar de forma direta.

Pode ver mais em [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101).

Acho que está um pouco defasado: [Linguagem de programação que não necessitem instalação prévia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117797/101) (na época todas implementações rodam de forma parecida e exigiam um ambiente instalado).

> Todo sistema operacional, tais como Windows, MacOS, Linux, etc. já vem com a JVM instalada para interpretar o programa feito em Java? Ou quando compila o programa `b.exe` já vem com a JVM embutida?

Os sistemas operacionais não costumam vir com o JRE instalado (o Android é uma exceção, mas não é o JRE padrão que está nele, ele tem o ART). Para a forma mais comum do Java precisa instalá-lo antes de usar. Mas como foi dito antes tem implementação que o *runtime* pode estar junto da sua aplicação, aí não precisa instalar nada previamente.

[Java não é interpretada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101).

> Porque para usar um programa Java precisa do JRE, e para desenvolvê-lo precisa de um JDK?

JDK é o SDK do Java, pode ver em [O que é um SDK?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191584/101). O JRE (Java Runtime Environment) é o ambiente instalado onde tem *runtime* e o que precisa para a aplicação rodar.

Talvez isso ajude: [O que significa "Rodar na JVM"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227279/101).

Apesar de ser .NET ajuda explicar o que é o *runtime*, os detalhes são diferentes, mas a ideia é a mesma: [O que é realmente o "runtime environment"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101)

Pode parecer confuso e uma resposta pode ajudar: [Afinal, Java é uma plataforma ou uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266489/101).

Pode interessar: [Relação entre HotSpot e JVM, JDK/OpenJDK?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227073/101) e [O que é a GraalVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325531/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito bem entendi tudo obrigado

Comment: @GutobritodoSantos veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.